# Will Quickblox support Windows 10 (Mobile)

Tags: quickblox

I am currently making an app on Android and planning to make it available on Windows 10 Mobile and “project astoria” is not available and will not any time soon. So  my question.
Will Quickblox support Windows 10 (Mobile) anytime soon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, QuickBlox does support Windows 10

Here is a link to main .NET documentation page, with SDK and code samples

http://quickblox.com/developers/DotNet

Comment: Thanks for your answer now I have two more questions.
firsts why is there no easy way to get to this documentation? Like a link on the left navigation. And second there are the servers located because I would prefer if they there in the EU.